# PHP: how many classes can have multiple interfaces implemented?

Tags: php

For e.g in a PHP , I need a clarification for the below

1. If i have multiple PHP classes which implements many interfaces. Is there any issues ?

Question 1)  Is there any limitation which tells that no of classes which implements many interfaces should be on this limit.

Question2)  Will there be any performance issue if multiple classes implements multiple interfaces?

Comment: Can you post some example code to show the problem you're facing?

Comment: Currently there is no issue , for PHP language we have the standards defined , so i came across a standard which tells that  "No of classes which implements multiple interfaces should not be more" . I want to clarify this . What kind of problems will it give if we have more classes which implements multiple interfaces